# Allow to open image in app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, images

When post contains an image without target link:

> [image: meta]

Or when target link is same as in-place link:

> [image: meta]

They will be opened in-app while tapping and all is fine and I'm happy.

But if target link is different, in particular links to more detailed high-res image, it will be opened in the preferred browser (in Chrome in my case):

> [image: meta]

Is it possible to allow to open such images in-app without need to switch to browser?

Possible solutions would be to check link extension or preload some data to detect image by header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be better in 1.6.6.1.

As Patrick pointed out, images in the app may link to any number of things.  As a result, we were only opening images in the app if the URL exactly matched.

But, and this is largely because I love doing it so much myself, now if the image is a Stack Exchange Imgur image with s, b, t, m, l, or h before the extension and it otherwise matches the link URL, I'll open the link in the app rather than the browser.

Other mismatched links will still be sent to the browser.

Comment: Don't forget about **s** parameter with specific size: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230362/339911

Answer (score 1):

There is more than just images. If the url is the same, they know it is an image for sure. From what I see, they don't treat the high-res image as an image, but as an external link instead (which is common on some sites where images link to sites instead of high-res versions of the same image).

I guess the problem is: they don't want to open a link in the app just see if the content type is an image. Instead they treat all 'other' links the same.

While I agree there is a good case for high-res images to be shown in-app, I can also understand the design decision made.

I would suggest to check on the domain from the external link, next to the current method. Is it from the SE Imgur account? Then always open it as an image in the app. If not, and the url is not the same as the image url, then open in a browser window.