# Open image from comment in app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, images

Recently I posted a [FR about opening image in app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295674/339911). It is completed now. Thanks, Brian. Now I want to extend that idea to comments like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296645/items-in-top-bar-become-gray-after-selecting-edit-in-the-your-communities-sect/296647#comment962578_296647).

Is it possible to open imgur links from comments in app?